# Brown streaks on neon pothos

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health

l have this neon pothos, not sure if it's variegated (l suppose so) cause it has real neon leaves on top and the variegated one at the bottom, but the older leaves have these marks shown in the picture. Does anybody know what those are?[image]

Comment: They're really interesting whatever they are. None of the affected leaves are dying? I'm not convinced it's a disease by the appearance, so far.